# How do I use Flare (data visualization) with only Flash CS3? I don't have Flex

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flash-cs3, data-visualization, flare

How do i use http://flare.prefuse.org/ with Flash CS3 in AS3. I don't intend to use Flex.

Please tell me the simplest way to do that. I am just a novice in Flash

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can do that. It's been covered here in the Flare forums: 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/prefuse/forums/forum/757572/topic/3060028